# What's the correct approach when an app needs access to a particular file?

Tags: files, permissions

I encountered an interesting (at least to me - a newbie in Linux) scenario today. I connected my drone to my Linux PC. Drone configuration software (Betaflight) couldn't connect to the drone. A quick google search solved the problem. Basically when I connect a drone with an USB cable a file is created: `/dev/ttyUSB0` and it has `660` permissions. The owner of the file is `root`, the group of the file is `uucp`. So the simple solution was to chmod this file to `666`. However that raised some questions in my head.

I've just added `r` and `w` permissions to this file to *everybody*, which seems excessive. Alternatively I think I could have added the Betaflight to `uucp` group which seems stupid, because it's an important group or ran it with sudo which seems even worse.

What's the proper way to handle this? Logically it would make sense to add a rule specifically for Betaflight to have `rw` access to this particular file. I'm just curious what's the "Linux way". I don't want to give a random app an excessive access to my OS, neither do I want to give any app/user access to a particular file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome Andrzej to Unix&Linux,

If you want to be minimal about the permissions you give, I’d suggest you:

1. create a dedicated group (let’s name it `drone`): `addgroup drone`
2. change your `/dev/ttyUSB0` to the group `drone`: `chgrp drone /dev/ttyUSB0`
3. change your drone configuration software (let’s call it `/usr/bin/foo`) to the group `drone` and enable the `setgid` bit: `chgrp drone /usr/bin/foo; chmod g+s /usr/bin/foo`
4. optionally disallow `other` to execute the configuration software and give dedicated user(s) (let’s call  it `user1`) permission to execute it with file ACLs: `chmod o-x /usr/bin/foo; setfacl -m u:user1:r-x /usr/bin/foo`

You may replace 3 and 4 with using `sudo` to allow the dedicated user(s) to run the configuration software as group `drone`. You would add in your `/etc/sudoers`:

```
user1 ALL=(:drone) /usr/bin/foo
```

And then use it as `user1`: `sudo -g drone foo`

Answer (score 1):

The answer can vary between different Linux distributions.

In the early Unix age, when serial lines and modems were the most common mode of networking between computers, email and file transfers were handled by a software suite known as Unix-to-Unix-Copy, or `uucp`. To ensure that regular users could not mess with things like scheduled email transfers between systems, access to serial ports used for outgoing connections were often assigned to a special group that was often named `uucp`. The programs of the uucp suite were assigned a `setgid uucp` permission, that would allow those programs - and *only* those programs to access the outgoing serial ports without root privileges.

A regular user would be allowed to run some of the tools of the uucp suite, but those tools would themselves contain the necessary checks to avoid mischief.

Apparently your Linux distribution still honors this old naming convention. On modern systems, the actual `uucp` software suite is very unlikely to be ever used, so the `uucp` group could be used to control access to serial ports in whatever way is sensible to the system's owner. Some distributions use a group with a different name, like `dialout` to manage serial ports, as the name `uucp` is opaque and unintuitive for anyone who does not know this bit of Unix history.

I think some Unix specifications used to require (or at least recommend) that the `uucp` group should always exist as a pre-defined system group on any compliant Unix-like system.

Some distributions actually pre-define a number of groups that can be used to allow specific users access to devices of particular type, like `cdrom`, `audio`, `video`, `plugdev` or `scanner` in Debian and related distributions.

`/dev/ttyUSB0` is not just a regular file: it is a *device node*. In modern Linux distributions, device nodes are managed by `udev` and are stored in a RAM-based filesystem, so if you use `chmod`, `chown` or `chgrp` to change their ownership or permissions, those changes will not persist over a reboot.

Because of this, you have several options:

- If you want **any user** to be able to use the serial ports **with particular programs only**, you could add a `setuid uucp` permissions to those programs:

```
sudo chgrp uucp /some/where/Betaflight
sudo chmod g+s /some/where/Betaflight
```

- If you want **only some users** to be able to use serial ports, you could add those users to the `uucp` group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G uucp username
```

Note: group memberships are assigned to user sessions at login time, so if a user is already logged-in when this change is made, the user will need to logout and login again to make the change effective.

- If you want **only the user physically at the computer** (and not users logged in remotely e.g. over SSH) to have access to serial ports, `systemd-logind` (if used) or PAM modules can be used to give extra access to device nodes for users that are actually logged on the console.

In older distributions, this could happen by either transferring the ownership of the specified devices to the user for the duration of their session and back to root once the session was over, or by granting extra group memberships at login time to the user that is logged on locally. Modern implementations tend to use Access Control Lists (ACLs) on the devices instead for this purpose, as the support for ACLs for the `devtmpfs` filesystem has matured and become ubiquitous.

With `systemd-logind`, you can assign a device to the control of the locally logged-in user by adding an udev rule with a `TAG+="seat"` for the device.